# Check for changes in a text file

Tags: c#

I need a simple way to monitor a text file for changes. Don't need any components just some function or just how this can be done.

I was thinking about checking the filesize for any changes, would this be a recomended was to monitor changes?

Comment: Check the FileSystemWatcher class out.

Comment: Something like this?: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Are you going to run monitoring program continuously?

Comment: The answer is yes Ulugbek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

There is an `OnChanged` event handler.

```
  var w = new FileSystemWatcher();

  w.Path = @"C:\SomePath";
  w.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
  w.Filter = "*.txt";
  w.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
  w.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

Then:

```
private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    // TODO
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) object provided by .NET

There is a full sample with source code on [Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26528/C-Application-to-Watch-a-File-or-Directory-using-F)

Answer (score 1):

While most answers point to FileSystemWatcher I think it's only one step in a more complicated process.

How far you have to go depends on the actual business case, which you didn't share with us, so I'll list a number of things you can do to detect changes, further down the list tightens the detection precision at the expense of complexity and performance

- If you're monitoring continuously hook up your logic on startup and on a FileSystemWatcher
- Check file's timestamps and size
- Check the first few and last few bytes
- Checksum the file:

  -- XOR (fast)
  -- CRC32
  -- MD5
  -- SHA256 (slow, secure)
- store an exact copy (overkill by any stretch of imagination)

So are you talking about sending yourself a tweet when your motion-triggered bird cam takes a picture or are you talking about detecting a change in a certificate file? The approaches differ.